# unable to boot win7 after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

hello i am new to Ubuntu and Linux too,
Recently i replaced Ubuntu with win7 after that when i tried to install win back for using both OS i got a problem. its not installing win7 or other versions of windows. in case when i tried to  boot Ubuntu again is not installing anything .
no boot menu appears just it takes me to the Ubuntu desktop.

[i did not created any hard disk partition for Ubuntu or win ]

I have no idea What to do. i need help .
please if you know how to solve it then tell me i think it may help other.
Thank for Reading this

Comment: Does the windows setup start after when you insert the installation medium before booting?

Answer (score 0):

Install **Boot-Repair** to reinstall GRUB and fix boot problems.

In a new terminal, type the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Launch Boot-Repair and click on *Recommended repair*.

With Boot-Repair, you can also create a Bootinfo summary to make a report of your boot problems before reinstalling GRUB. This report need to be posted here for further analysis.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Post link to Boot-Repair's summary report in your post above. Windows will only install to a blank drive or a primary partition formatted NTFS with the boot flag already created. It will not boot from a logical partition.

Comment: thanks for your response but when i tried to recommended boot repair it returns error masg .like:  GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.